# Restarting IIS publishes old/cached Umbraco content

Tags: iis, umbraco, umbraco7

We are experiencing an issue whereby upon the restart of IIS, our Umbraco site is reverting to old content/branding. The log reads that umbraco.content is loading XML from file

Only 1 of the 7 sites in IIS is affected by this behaviour. We are running the full version of MS-SQL Server (not SQL CE)

Where is Umbraco getting this content from and how can we prevent it happening when IIS restarts (a nightly task). Is there an Umbraco setting that is only present on this specific database/config?

The logs read:

```
2016-05-11 12:50:37,715 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.CoreBootManager - [T29/D5] Umbraco application starting
2016-05-11 12:50:37,762 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Determining hash of code files on disk
2016-05-11 12:50:37,793 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Hash determined (took 18ms)
2016-05-11 12:50:37,793 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Starting resolution types of umbraco.interfaces.IApplicationStartupHandler
2016-05-11 12:50:37,809 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Completed resolution of types of umbraco.interfaces.IApplicationStartupHandler, found 38 (took 10ms)
2016-05-11 12:50:37,949 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Starting resolution types of Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.IPropertyEditorValueConverter
2016-05-11 12:50:37,949 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Completed resolution of types of Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.IPropertyEditorValueConverter, found 0 (took 0ms)
2016-05-11 12:50:37,949 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Starting resolution types of Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.IPropertyValueConverter
2016-05-11 12:50:37,949 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Completed resolution of types of Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.IPropertyValueConverter, found 16 (took 1ms)
2016-05-11 12:50:37,965 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Starting resolution types of Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
2016-05-11 12:50:37,965 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Completed resolution of types of Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController, found 14 (took 1ms)
2016-05-11 12:50:37,965 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Starting resolution types of Umbraco.Web.WebApi.UmbracoApiController
2016-05-11 12:50:37,980 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Completed resolution of types of Umbraco.Web.WebApi.UmbracoApiController, found 61 (took 10ms)
2016-05-11 12:50:38,043 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Starting resolution types of Umbraco.Core.Media.IThumbnailProvider
2016-05-11 12:50:38,043 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Completed resolution of types of Umbraco.Core.Media.IThumbnailProvider, found 3 (took 0ms)
2016-05-11 12:50:38,043 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Starting resolution types of Umbraco.Core.Media.IImageUrlProvider
2016-05-11 12:50:38,059 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [T29/D5] Completed resolution of types of Umbraco.Core.Media.IImageUrlProvider, found 1 (took 6ms)
2016-05-11 12:50:39,809 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Search.ExamineEvents - [T29/D5] Initializing Examine and binding to business logic events
2016-05-11 12:50:39,996 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Search.ExamineEvents - [T29/D5] Adding examine event handlers for index providers: 3
2016-05-11 12:50:39,996 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Core.CoreBootManager - [T29/D5] Umbraco application startup complete (took 2282ms)
2016-05-11 12:50:41,293 [35] INFO  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [T34/D5] Setting OriginalRequestUrl: xxx.xxx.com/umbraco
2016-05-11 12:50:41,465 [35] INFO  umbraco.content - [T34/D5] Load Xml from file...
2016-05-11 12:50:41,465 [35] INFO  umbraco.content - [T34/D5] Loaded Xml from file.
```

Comment: Is the umbraco.config file in App_Data changing when you save & publish content in back-office?

Comment: Yes it is. It updates fine UNTIL IIS is restarted and then it reverts

Comment: Umbraco does store the XML for each node in the database so it can quickly re-build the umbraco.config cache.

Comment: What happens if you change a node, then republish the entire site via the menu on the "Content" item in the Content section?

Comment: @BeaverProj - the umbraco.config file is correct after amending a node and then republishing the entire site. When we perform an IIS restart and Umbraco also restarts, the file is recreated with old, out-of-date data

Comment: Right, but I'm asking, does the rollback happen when you do the "fast" republish on the main Content node?